# Datatable select greater than date

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have populated a datatable with MySQL data, and I need to retrieve all records from the datatable where "unitassign" is DBNull AND the "putime"(MySQL datetime format) is greater than or equal to today's date (even if the time already passed) AND the "putime"(same variable) is less than or equal to a vbdatetime variable "eighthr" (this one would be matching based off date and time)

```
Dim eighthr As DateTime
If (DateTime.Now.AddHours(8).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) Then
    eighthr = CDate(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
Else
    eighthr = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8)
End If
resultstr = "unitassign is Null AND (putime >= #" & SchedulerControl1.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "# AND putime <= #" & eighthr & "#)"

Dim result() As DataRow = jboardtable.Select(resultstr)
```

this is returning no results although I do have rows in my datatable that should be appearing

Comment: `eighthr` looks like a string or a date.  Make up your mind.  Try using `Option Strict On`

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: syntax is not operating correctly. LarsTech - I am trying to look at it now

Comment: option strict on  and analyzer recommended adding one Cdate to  the line before the else (as shown) no other errors - Still no change in my problem

Comment: 1) You are comparing `putime >= #" & SchedulerControl1..` instead of today's date, are you sure `SchedulerControl1.Start` is today's date. 2) Your else block is `eighthr = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8)` try to format it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or whatever its required format is. 3) You must compare it in your column data format, i.e. confirm whether your putime column in datatable is a datetime column and also its format `M/d/yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd` or something else

Comment: You said, "MySQL Format" but it is important for you to understand that `DataTable.Select()` is always dotNet format, regardless of your database.

Comment: actually, I missed part of the Question - steve's comment is dead on: once you have the data in a DataTable the MySql Date format is irrelevant!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim eighthr As DateTime
If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours < 16 Then
    eighthr = DateTime.Now.Date
Else
    eighthr = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)
End If
resultstr = "unitassign is Null AND (putime >= #" & SchedulerControl1.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "# AND putime <= #" & eighthr & "#)"
Dim result() As DataRow = jboardtable.Select(resultstr)
```

Comment: this doesn't work - seems to be doing pretty identical to what my erroneous code above

Comment: I just fixed a "typo" in resultstr caused by autocorrect. Also, is SchedulerControl1.Start less than today's date?